# Why is there a space before first column in skeleton?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using skeleton. I am using one-third column three times. But the third one is not on the same line and is breaking away from the row. It is in the next line. 
Also there is a white space before the first column.

[image]

I am using following HTML code!

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Feature</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Perfomance</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Trial</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML is not relevant. Check the CSS file and post it if you still can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `margin-left` for `.column` is `4%` and the `width` of each column is `30.6667%`, so that adds up to `(30.6667% + 4%) * 3 = 104.0001%`. That is pushing the last column to the next line.

You need to overwrite the `margin-left` to `2.6%`, which will add up to `(30.6667% + 2.6%) * 3 = 99.8001%`

```css
.column {
  margin-left: 2.6% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Feature</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Perfomance</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Trial</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/dof4nuoy/) and it seems to work fine. I'm using [skeleton.css v2.0.4](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/skeleton) in the fiddle.

Comment: @Vucko - It doesn't work on the snippet if I don't overwrite the `margin-left`. I've added a Snippet to the original question.

Comment: We're using the same version of skeleton.css, yet in the fiddle works fine. It seems that media querys aren't working in the fiddle (they are overwritten by `.one-third.column`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You also gave nice explanation :) I think I should report it to skeleton developers for the bug!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is wrapping these 3 "one-third column" with  ... columns here ..

@chipChocolate we use CSS frameworks for avoiding this kind of detailed calculations. adding row is framework's provided way.

I hope this helps

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row"><!-- row for one-third -->
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Feature</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Perfomance</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="one-third column feature">
  <h2>Trial</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur.</p>
</div>
</div><!-- End of row -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put your code between   `<div class="row">` and `</div>`

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.